# .Net 6 Upgrade from Framework 4.8 (API Project)

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, upgrade, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

I am upgrading each project in my solution. I was able to complete the class libraries upgrade and now I have a Web API project to be upgraded. In short, I have added a new project Asp.Net Core Web API and resolving all dependencies.

I have landed up with an issue "The name 'RequestContext' does not exist in the current context" for the below line of code:

var tempName = RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;

In 4.8, RequestContext was HttpRequestContext from System.Web.Http

Looking for an alternative in .net 6 to achieve the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Asp.Net Core, Components with access to the current `HttpContext` (middleware, for example) can get the current user's `ClaimsPrincipal` from `HttpContext.User`.

So, You can use this code to get what you want.

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

Please refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/claimsprincipal-current?view=aspnetcore-7.0#retrieve-the-current-user-in-an-aspnet-core-app) to learn more.

Comment: Hi @Lucky, Can this answer help you solve your issue?

Comment: Yes it does thanks a lot and sorry for delay in responding

Comment: Can you also help me with a couple of more: I have a class inheriting from IAuthenticationFilter and implements AuthenticationAsync and ChallengeAsync. What do I do?

Comment: @Lucky, In stackoverflow, a post generally only addresses one question, You can post another question, It will make more people to help you.